# iOS app taking photos / images while running in background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1

Is it possible to make an ios7 app that takes images automatically every hour or so? even when its running in the background and the iphone is not being used? And if yes, how?
thank you in advance

Comment: No, you can't access the camera from the background

Comment: iOS doesn't do much in the way of background tasks.

Comment: Apple restricts apps from doing anything in background except for special cases. Lookup iOS background tasks.

Answer (score -2):

What about jailbreaking the iphone, using the app with all possible hacks?